# How to add a text in a certain div when click in a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my first incursion in jQuery so I am really newbie with this. I read the documentation (actually, I am still on it) to get to know it better!

The thing is that I have a website with several links into a li element and I want to achieve that every time I click in one of these links, a certain piece of text will appear in a div id="container" in the webpage.

How could I do this?

Comment: Where will this text come from? I mean, how are you relating the li with the corresponding text?

Comment: well the text is supposed to be a description when clicking the link, which is supposed to be a menu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('li a').click(function(){
   $('#container').html('Text you want to add');
});
```

Comment: this would produce the same result for each link.  still a useful answer however.

Answer (score 4):

Quick, simple answer:

```
$('#yourlist li a').click(function(){
    //grab link's href attribute
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    //update content
    $('#container').html("Loading page " + href + "...");

    //load page via AJAX using link's href
    $('#container').load(href);
});
```

I added more code to show how you would access the given link using `$(this)` and further load its href via AJAX.

Comment: why not delegate? Imagine 100 li's

Comment: why use ajax for such a simple task??

Comment: It's purely for example to demonstrate how to do something with specific link using `$(this)`.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<script src="your/downloaded/jquery/path.js></script>       
<script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a#idOfLink').click(function() {
            $("div#container").html("<span class='red'>Your certain text</span>");
         });
     })
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin .. I often make typo in `function` :p